@update на VAutocomplete
<VAutocomplete
        class="px-8 relative"
        label="Поиск"
        placeholder="Введите запрос..."
        variant="outlined"
        hide-details
        persistent-clear
        clearable
        locale="ru"
        prepend-inner-icon="mdi:search"
        @update:modelValue="handleSearch"
    >
      <template slot="item"
      v-for="(item,i) in searchResult.value.data"
      >
        <NuxtLink :to="item.url">{{item.fields.title}}</NuxtLink>
      </template>
    </VAutocomplete>

Испрозую вот такой VAutocomplete для реализация поиска. @update:model-value не срабатывает.
const search = ref<string | undefined>(undefined)

const searchResult = ref<any>('')

const handleSearch = async (value: string) => {

  value === '' ? search.value = undefined : search.value = value

  console.log(value)
  console.log(value.length)

  if(value && value?.length > 3) {
    const { data } = await useAPI(
        `/search/${config.name.split('-').at(-1)}?site=${config.name.split('-').at(-1)}&query=${value}`,
    )
    searchResult.value = data
    console.log(searchResult.value._rawValue.data)
  }
}

вот функция обработки запроса. по какой причине может не срабатывать @update:modelValue? (value в функцию, по логированию, не поступает)
